# linux sudo list permitted commands

Tags: linux, sudo

Given that `/etc/sudoers` and `/etc/sudoers.d/` are not readable by regular users, is there a way that I, as a normal user, can find out what `sudo` permissions I have?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run `sudo -l`.

Depending on how `sudo` is configured on your system, it might request your password first, but it will display all `sudo` configuration options that apply to your account, and then all the permitted command definitions applicable to you.

Answer (score 14):

Use `sudo -l` to get your access rights. The output might look like this:

```bash
#> sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for myuser on myhost:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin, !fqdn,
    use_pty

User myuser may run the following commands on myhost:
    (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl restart docker
    (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl restart docker.service
```

If you do not have access rights, it asks for password and writes a message:

```bash
#> sudo -l
[sudo] password for myuser:
Sorry, user myuser may not run sudo on myhost.
```

Answer (score -4):

Create a script to traverse `$PATH`, looking for executables, and run it with `sudo` to look at the `sudo` environment. Also remember that one can use an absolute path: `sudo /media/walt/newsys/install`.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
find $( echo "$PATH" | tr ':' ' ') -type f -executable -print | \
    sort
```

Run this both with `sudo` and without.

Comment: This won't help if (as is quite likely in the OP's case) the script you've just written isn't one of the scripts that `sudo` is set up to allow you to run.

Comment: `sudo` can restrict not just which commands you can run, but which command-line options you can use.